# unsupervised learning on sentences

Tags: machine-learning

I have a data that represents comments from the operator on various activities performed on a industrial device. The comments, could reflect either a routine maintainence/replacement activity or could represent that some damage occured and it had to be repaired to rectify the damage.
I have a set of 200,000 sentences that needs to be classified into two buckets - Repair/Scheduled Maintainence(or undetermined). These have no labels, hence looking for an unsupervised learning based solution.

Some sample data is as shown below:

"Motor coil damaged .Replaced motor"
"Belt cracks seen. Installed new belt"
"Occasional start up issues. Replaced switches"

"Replaced belts"
"Oiling and cleaning done".
"Did a preventive maintainence schedule"

The first three sentences have to be labeled as Repair while the second three as Scheduled maintainence.

What would be a good approach to this problem. though I have some exposure to Machine learning I am new to NLP based machine learning.

I see many papers related to this https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a408/d3b5b37caefb93629273fa3d0c192668d63c.pdf
https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07897

but wanted to understand if there is any standard approach to such problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could use some reliable keywords (verbs it seems in this case) to create training samples for an NLP Classifier. Or you could use KMeans or KMedioids clustering and use 2 as K, which would do a pretty good job of separating the set. If you want to get really involved, you could use something like Latent Derichlet Allocation, which is a form of unsupervised topic modeling. However, for a problem like this, on the small amount of data you have, the fancier you get the more frustrated with the results you will become IMO.

Both OpenNLP and StanfordNLP have text classifiers for this, so I recommend the following if you want to go the classification route:

```
- Use key word searches to produce a few thousand examples of your two categories
- Put those sentences in a file with a label based on the OpenNLP format (label |space| sentence | newline )
- Train a classifier with the OpenNLP DocumentClassifier, and I recommend stemming for one of your feature generators
- after you have the model, use it in Java and classify each sentence.
- Keep track of the scores, and quarantine low scores (you will have ambiguous classes I'm sure)
```

If you don't want to go that route, I recommend using a text indexing technology de-jeur like SOLR or ElasticSearch or your favorite RDBMS's text indexing to perform a "More like this" type function so you don't have to play the Machine learning continuous model updating game.

Comment: thanks for the options,I will explore the options.One question though, to do  KMeans, what would be a good suggestion to vectorize the sentence, such that it still preserves the meaning,.

Comment: "meaning" is hard to preserve (and define!), but in general NGrams can help maintain context, because it preserves some amount of order. Often times I will produce both BIGrams and Bag Of Words "features" to cluster with. One challenge will be sparse vector normalization, because obviously each sentence is not a "real valued' vector space. For the small amount of data you have, you can easily normalize them.